# Laravel 5.6 login, incompatibilidad con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, login

estoy intentando hacer el login con laravel 5.6, mi version de php es la 7.3.11.

He ejecutado la comanda 'php artisan make:auth' y yo tengo entendido(si me equivoco corrijanme) que esta se encarga de todo el tema de cifrado de contraseñas.

**Si cuándo hace la migracion de la tabla users y yo inserto un usuario des de el phpmyadmin esta contraseña se deberia de cifrar sola al momento de agregar el usuario? O yo deberia especificar de entre las siguientes opciones?**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
--Tengo esta duda porque no me funciona el login(me da error que NO coinciden las credenciales) y me han dicho que es porque no cifra la contraseña y que es posible que haya una incompatibilidad de versiones de php, mysql ,comanda auth de laravel...

No publico el código porque creo que el problema real esta en las versiones, pero igualmente mas tarde lo publicare, espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El propio comando `php artisan make:auth` ya te crea los formularios y controladores para registro.

Lo que hace este controlador es hashear (no cifrar) el texto que tu pasas como contraseña, y almacena el resultado como texto plano.

Despues el propio controlador de login ya hace el paso inverso, por eso te da ese error, porque al convertir la cadena que le pasas al login no coincide.

PD: nunca almacenes tus contraseñas en texto plano.

Comment: +1, las contraseñas nunca han de estar visibles. Y en Laravel en la tabla Users se guarda un hash. Lo único que hace el motor de laravel es coger la cadena que le pasas, la convierte en un hash y las compara a ver si los 2 hash coinciden. Como no coincide, peta.

Comment: Pero entonces si yo inserto un user des de phpmyadmin, ese usuario nunca podrá acceder mediante el login? supongo que la respuesta es no.Es posbile hashear la contraseña desde el phpmyadmin?

Comment: @smiranda podria acceder si el campo que añades como contraseña es un hash válido. Desde esta web http://www.passwordtool.hu/php5-password-hash-generator puedes crear el hash, aunque te recomiendo que lo hagas desde el formulario de registro

Comment: Vale si funciona...PERFECTO! Claro es que yo queria hacer el formulario de registro depués de comprobar que funcione el login y por eso metia el usuario desde phpmyadmin, ya me he aclarado con algunas dudas, gracias a los 2!

Answer (score 1):

Como bien te dicen, `php artisan make:auth` solo crea las vistas, controladores y rutas para utilizar la autentificación de laravel que viene por defecto, la cual en la parte del registrar una nueva cuenta, el controlador se encarga de guardar la contraseña encriptada.

Si quieres entender como funciona puedes copiar el siguiente código al final de routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {

    $user = new App\User();
    $user->email = 'usuario@gmail.com';
    $user->name = 'Usuario Test';
    $user->password = bcrypt('123456');
    $user->save();

    dd("se ha guardado el usuario con éxito");
});
```

De esta forma se creará un usuario con la clave 123456 pero encriptada.

La autentificación de Laravel solo funciona con la clave encriptada, por lo que si quieres utilizarla deberás encriptar la password del usuario cada vez que se registre o crees un nuevo usuario.